# Will a ball spin in place if the friction force is high enough?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, friction, projectile

Pretty simple question. If we have a ball on a ramp with angle $ \theta $ and therefore a component of gravity acting along the ramp equal to $mg \sin(\theta) $ and a friction force that is exactly equivalent to the force due to gravity, according to Newton's 2nd law, the ball should not move. But due to the applied torque the ball should spin. So will the ball spin in place?

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, a ball on a slope experiencing a large friction force will have a torque but no downward sliding motion.  This is because the friction forces point up the slope (orthogonal to the normaal force) and generated at the point of contact with the slope (below the center of mass--this causes a torque).

If we were considering a block, the torque would be countered by a normal force on the downhill side of the block to prevent the block from spinning.  As this is a ball and has only a si gle point of contact (this is not actually true, but we'll assume it is to simplify the concept).

In the case of the ball, as we do not counter the torque, the ball will gain angular momentum and begin to roll [rather than slide--friction is preventing the ball from sliding] down the plane.
The ball cannot spin in place due to friction alone as friction itself would act against the spin.

[image: Forces acting on a mass sliding down an inclined plane.]

See also:
https://byjus.com/coefficient-of-static-friction-formula/

Answer (score -1):

> friction force that is exactly equivalent to the force due to gravity

This cannot happen. The friction force depends on the relative velocity of the surfaces in friction. If the relative velocity is zero, which is the case for rolling, the magnitude of the friction force can be anywhere between zero and $k |N|$. So the ball will just roll down (unless the rolling friction is very high).

Comment: Yes but what happens when the rolling friction is very high?

Comment: @EmilSriram : Then the ball will be at rest.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi : Your comment looks self-contradictory, as if there is only one point of contact, there is no rolling friction (and there is infinite pressure in this point).

Comment: why is friction always less? The friction force would be mgcos(theta) * coefficient of friction, which if theta is small enough, will be a lot greater than gravity.

Comment: @akhmeteli wouldn't there still be a torque though caused by friction?

Comment: @EmilSriram :  "The friction force would be mgcos(theta) * coefficient of friction " I respectfully disagree. If the body is at rest on a horizontal plane and there are no other horizontal forces but friction, the friction is zero, not mg * coefficient of friction. There is no relative movement in the point of contact in case of rolling, so the friction can be less than what you say.

Comment: @EmilSriram : "wouldn't there still be a torque though caused by friction?" Not with respect to the axis of rotation.

Comment: @akhmeteli ok but with respect to the axis of rotation there would be a torque caused by gravity then, no?

Comment: @EmilSriram : Yes, but it is an instantaneous axis of rotation, so in a moment it will be a different axis of rotation lower on the ramp, so the ball will be rolling down.